# Frontier 6.2.1 ODBC Connection

Tags: windows-7, dll, odbc, regsvr32

We've got an application that's using a Frontier (UserLand) database. I'm not at all familiar with this type of system or object-oriented database structures in general. So, I'm trying to connect with it the best I know how, through SQL Server Management Studio.

In the applications directory, there was a document outlining how to initialize ODBC for Windows. I followed the instructions in the documentation that essentially created an ODBC.DLL file. I tried to then use "regsvr32" to register the DLL, but I get the "....'dll' was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found." error.

Any direction into properly setup an ODBC connection using a DLL can help narrow down my search options.

**Update**
I ran the following commands from a batch file where the DLL was located:

```
@copy odbc.dll %systemroot%\system32\
@%systemroot%\system32\regsvr32 odbc.dll
```

odbc.dll is the file that was generated from the Frontier script.

Comment: Please update your question to list the exact commands you were using and the exact commands from the documentation

Comment: odbc.dll is suppose to be Microsoft DLL it shouldn't be generated from script.

Comment: You mean odbc32.dll? That DLL wasn't overwritten.

Comment: You are sure this odbc.dll is a COM library file?

Comment: I suspect this script creates a copy of `Microsoft.Data.Odbc.dll` for whatever reasons, which means it's a .NET library, and does not and cannot be registered by regsvr32. The only reference related to `Frontier` and `Odbc.dll` is a discussion surrounding `Microsoft.Data.Odbc.dll`

Comment: Do you have a reference to that discussion? Also, I discovered that the Db structure can use Fat Pages, so I'll continue down that route as well.

Comment: No;  I no longer have a reference to that discussion, I didn't think I required one, I am asking questions to clarify your problem.